# When trying to run a gam system command from a python script, it returns a permission denied error?

Tags: python, linux, bash, gam

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, bash, and the python script is being run in venv.

I can use gam on the command line without a problem, however when I try to do an os.system command in my python script like:

```
os.system("gam csv account.csv gam update user ~EmailAddress org ~Abbrev")
```

I return:

```
sh: 1: gam: Permission denied
```

I have set gam/home/USER/googlesync/venv/bin as part of my .bashrc file  PATH.

Writing the GAM command directly into the command line will run the command and update all of the accounts.

A daily.sh file

```
#!/bin/sh

python connection.py
gam csv accounts.csv gam create user ~EmailAddress password ~Password firstname ~FirstName lastname ~LastName org ~Abbrev
gam csv accounts.csv gam update user ~EmailAddress org ~Abbrev
```

Resulted in

```
sh: 1: gam: Permission denied
sh: 1: gam: Permission denied
daily.sh: 4: gam: Permission denied
daily.sh: 5: gam: Permission denied
```

When trying to sudo daily.sh the error becomes

```
daily.sh: 3: python: not found
daily.sh: 4: gam: not found
daily.sh: 5: gam: not found
```

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 tech tech   235 Aug 10 08:48 daily.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tech tech 20803 Aug 10 09:11 powerschoolconnection.py
drwxrwxr-x 6 tech tech  4096 Jul 18 15:05 venv
```

Running

> which gam

does not return an output.

Running

> which -a gam

returns

> ./gam

Comment: Please add the output  of `which gam` and an `ls -l ` of that file to the question.

Comment: which gam does not return an output.

Comment: So, the shell cannot find `gam`. Yet you say that `gam` from the command line works? So where is `gam`? What if you use the complete path to `gam`  in your `os.system`?

Comment: I can see that gam is in ~/bin/gam. The full echo $PATH returns /home/tech/googlesync/venv/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:/home/tech/.local/bin:/home/tech/bin:/home/tech/bin:gam/home/tech/googlesync/venv/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:/home/tech/.local/bin:/home/tech/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:

Comment: And what is `ls -l ~/bin/gam`?

Comment: In your `PATH` there is `gam/home/tech/googlesync/venv/bin`. That is wrong.  That should probably be `~/bin/gam`.